# Line up Pictures in footer

Tags: html, css, image, footer

I recently added some icons to my site's footer: http://ininkk.com/

They ended up sitting below one another instead of being flush in one line. Specifically the payment options icon (all-in-one image) and the shipping icons (all-in-one).

Does anyone know how I can made them sit side by side but with a little space in between?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
.visamastercard, .shipna {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

There will be a space between the icon as long as the `img` tags aren't immediately adjacent to each other (i.e., there's a newline or space between the `img` tags).

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Stack says I've gotta wait 5 minutes before accepting your answer.